# Sharepoint 2013 CSS rotate not working

Tags: css, sharepoint, rotation, sharepoint-2013

I want to make text on the table header to rotate vertically. It works (text able to rotate) whenever I'm editing, but once I press save, the text will not rotate.

I check my css code for it, and the code for rotation is gone too. While editing, code was there.

While Editing and After Saving:
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wherever needed use !important to make sure required css is applied first irrespective of other code.
Reference: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like SharePoint not recognizing your CSS as a valid CSS.
Put your CSS in a text file save the text file in asset library then give reference in content editor webpart. Try this it might work...